# UITapGestureRecognizer not firing

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

Let's get the google results out of the way

- .userInteractionEnabled IS true
- The view IS hit (using a symbolic breakpoint with `-[UIWindow sendEvent:]` and `po $arg3`)

---

Now on to how I have this structured, which is an attempt to make models totally removed from view code.

The gist is that I have these classes:

[image: class diagram]

- class `CarModel` - pure data
- class `CarModelDisplayClass` - a class that carries a Model, and can conform to `Displayable` and `Tappable`. This is the class that the later BuilderClass will deal with, it basically acts as a bridge between the Models and the Views.
- protocol `Displayable` - To make a class return a view for the later BuilderClass to attach to a view/screen
- protocol `Tappable` - The BuilderClass looks at conformance to attach a tap gesture to the view (which is returned from the `Displayable` protocol))

The Builder works like this:

1. Hardcode-build a bunch of CarModels
2. Hardcode-build a bunch of CarModelDisplayClass with the models
3. Send the list of CarModelDisplayClass into a method that translates the list into actual views and gesture recognizers (by looking at protocol conformance)
4. Attach these views to an actual UIViewController
5. Present the UIViewController

At this point it all works, except the UITapGestureRecognizer.

The `CarModelDisplayClass` to actual views+gestures looks like this.

```
for item in items {
    let view = item.view() // Get the view from the Displayable protocol
    superView.addSubview(view)

    if let i = item as? Tappable { // Check Tappable conformance
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: i, action: #selector(i.tapped))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

I am not sure if there is something obvious I am missing. I thought maybe there is something related to the target `i` is the issue, however I have tried directing it to `item` as well (if that would even matter I don't know).

Any pointers would help.

---

I have the real code here (it has different names though)

- [The Displayable and Tappable protocols](https://github.com/jontelang/ThaiLanguageApp/blob/StackOverflowQuestion/App/thai-language-app-2/Pillars/TLAStackView/Protocols/TLAStackViewDisplayable.swift#L30-L44)
- [Pure model class](https://github.com/jontelang/ThaiLanguageApp/blob/StackOverflowQuestion/App/thai-language-app-2/App%20Flows/Characters/Model/TLACharacter.swift)
- [Example of a display class that takes a model and conforms to display to return a simple label, and conforms to tappable with a method](https://github.com/jontelang/ThaiLanguageApp/blob/StackOverflowQuestion/App/thai-language-app-2/App%20Flows/Characters/View/TLACharacterDisplay.swift)
- [The view builder that converts display classes into actual views and adds gesture recognizers to them if needed](https://github.com/jontelang/ThaiLanguageApp/blob/StackOverflowQuestion/App/thai-language-app-2/Pillars/TLAStackView/Builders/TLAStackviewBuilder.swift#L33-L48)
- [The high level builder that collects models, display classes and presents a VC](https://github.com/jontelang/ThaiLanguageApp/blob/StackOverflowQuestion/App/thai-language-app-2/App%20Flows/Characters/Builder/TLACharactersModuleBuilder.swift)

Comment: “The view IS hit” How do you know? When you touch the screen, what does `hitTest` return? It takes much more than userInteraction to make a view touchable. Maybe there is a view outside the bounds of its superview. Use the View Debugger. Or post the actual project so we can look.

Comment: Or maybe there is an objc missing. Remember that Objective C Cocoa is doing the work here.  Most swift code is invisible to it.

Comment: Without more detail in your code, I would wager something is stealing your taps. Try implementing this `gestureRecognizer(shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)` for UITapGestureRecognizer. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate. Where does your CarModelDisplayable live? Is it in a UICollectionViewCell or a UITableViewCell?

Comment: I know it is hit because the breakpoint I have that prints the touch event details says so. Anyway the answer was unrelated to touch hits and I have marked it as solved. Thanks regardless for the input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you will have to keep a strong reference to your Tappable items somewhere in code otherwise they will be removed from memory.

Based on the code in attached links - I would change TLAStackviewBuilder class to return UIScrollView, but with references to displayRows in it.

In code that you wrote above:

```
class Something {

  let storedItems: [Any]!

  func someFunc(items: Tappable) {
     storedItems = items

     for item in items {
        let view = item.view() // Get the view from the Displayable protocol
        superView.addSubview(view)

        if let i = item as? Tappable { // Check Tappable conformance
          let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: i, action: #selector(i.tapped))
          view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
          view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: This is indeed the problem.  I verified this fixes the issue by creating a subclass of `UIScrollView` that holds the displayRows and the tapping works.

Comment: Thank you! I had some thoughts that this would be the issue but couldn't put my finger on exactly what to do to fix it.